# binding data to table

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

How to bind data to using odata model? I'm getting error like Resource not found for the segment 'results'.

My code:

```
var url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZODATA_SERVICE_NAME";
        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url,false);

            oModel.read("/EntityDataSet", null, null, true, function(oData) {   

            that.getView().setModel(oModel,"student");      
                            },
                                function(error) {

        });


    <Table  headerDesign="Standard"

items="{student>/results}"
    id="table"  >
                <columns>
                    <Column  >
                        <header>
                            <Label   text="studentName" width="100%"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>

                    <Column >
                        <header>
                            <Label   text="studentRank" width="100%"/>
                        </header>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem  >
                        <cells>
                            text="{student>StudentName}"/>
                            text="{student>Rank}"/>

                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. the ODataMOdel you are using is deprecated, make sure to use the v2.ODataModel instead
2. you don't need to execute an HTTP call via JavaScript (ODataModel.read(...) ) to get the data in order to bind it to the table.
3. I think you did not clearly understand OData and models in UI5. Having a look at the official [SAPUI5 Tutorials](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218.html) might help you out.

Anyway, here is a [running jsbin example](https://jsbin.com/totizisuho/edit?html,output):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script
         src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->

        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">

                <Table
                    id="myTable"
                    growing="true"
                    growingThreshold="10"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    busyIndicatorDelay="0"
                    items="{/Customers('ALFKI')/Orders}">
                    <headerToolbar>
                        <Toolbar>
                            <Title text="Orders of ALFKI"/>
                            <ToolbarSpacer/>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </headerToolbar>
                    <columns>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="OrderID"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Order Date"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="To Name"/>
                        </Column>
                        <Column>
                            <Text text="Ship City"/>
                        </Column>
                    </columns>
                    <items>
                        <ColumnListItem type="Active">
                          <cells>
                              <ObjectIdentifier title="{OrderID}"/>

                              <Text
                                  text="{
                                      path:'OrderDate',
                                      type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                      formatOptions: {
                                        style: 'medium',
                                        strictParsing: true
                                      }
                                  }"/>

                              <Text text="{ShipName}"/>

                              <Text text="{ShipCity}"/>

                          </cells>
                        </ColumnListItem>
                    </items>
                </Table>

            </mvc:View>
        </script>

        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";

                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.define([
                    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
                    "sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel"
                ], function (Controller, ODataModel) {
                    "use strict";

                    return Controller.extend("MyController", {
                        onInit : function () {
                            // in component based apps you would not
                            // even need this piece of code:
                            this.getView().setModel(
                                new ODataModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/services.odata.org/V2/Northwind/Northwind.svc/", {
                                    json : true,
                                    useBatch : false
                                })
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });

                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");

            });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

that.getView().setModel(oModel,"student");

to

**this**.getView().setModel(oModel,"student");

Answer (score 0):

that.getView().setModel(oModel,"student");     //incorrect

this.getView().setModel(oModel,"student");   //refers to this particular controller